# Calculate residual values from trainfset or test set

Tags: python, machine-learning, linear-regression

I want to perform Residual analysis, and i know that residuals equal the observed values minus the predicted ones. But i don't know should i calculate residuals from the training set or the test set ?

Should i use this:

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm 
# Making predictions
lm = sm.OLS(y_train,X_train).fit()

y_pred = lm.predict(X_train)
resid = y_train - y_pred.to_frame('price')
```

OR this:

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm 
# Making predictions
lm = sm.OLS(y_train,X_train).fit()

y_pred = lm.predict(X_test)
resid = y_test- y_pred.to_frame('price')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The residual error should be computed from the actual values (expected outcome) of the test set `y_test` and the predicted values by the fitted model for `X_test`. The model is fitted to the training set and then its accuracy is tested on the test set. This is how I see it intuitively, the main reason in the first place to formally call the two datasets as `train` (for training) and then for testing (`test`).

Specifically, use the second case

```
resid = y_test- y_pred.to_frame('price')
```

Comment: For the purpose of regression the test and training set must be separated, but if you want to understand the modeling of the entire data set after regression has been completed then this would not be done and all data would be used.

Comment: @JamesPhillips so you're saying that residual analysis should be done before splitting. i didn't quiet understand. can you please explain more. Thanks

Comment: After model selection, which might include removing a predictor variable from the model as insignificant, you might want to run the model on the entire data set for final statistical analysis.